# Вывод изображения на экран из media django

Tags: python, django

Проблема состоит в том, что при выводе на экран изображения товара по id ничего не выводится, а если не фильтровать по id, то изображения выводятся как надо. Не могу понять в чем дело

views.py

```
def index(request, template_name, id):
    args={}
    if id:
        args[goods]=Goods.objects.filter(parent=id)
    else:
        args[goods]=Goods.objects.all()
    ..............
```

goods.html

```
{% for good in goods %}
   <img src={{good.img.url}} />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Скорее всего нет Goods, у которых parent равен значению id. Соответственно goods в шаблоне пустой.

Comment: Нет, есть. Выводится вся информация о зафильтрованных товарах и url правильный выводится, но изображение почему-то не выводится.

Comment: А если это url просто отдельно в новой вкладке открыть-то?

Comment: Все открывается так же как без фильтра по id

Answer (score 2):

В коде ошибок нет, значит их нужно искать на front end части.
Скорее всего когда происходит фильтрация по ID добавляется часть пути. Пример.

```
/goods/
/goods/3/
```

Когда перешли на вложенную страницу с ID изменился относительный путь до картинки.

т.е. по данному пути нет этой картинки
было media/img/pic.jpg, стало goods/media/img/pic.jpg.

не достаточно данных о том какой исходный код у результатирующей страницы.